# Firebase Push Notification send through http protocols click event analytics

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

Is there any way to get the count of the notifications clicked which are sent through firebase push notifications (fcm) HTTP protocol over web app?

Answer (score 0):

## *Notification Open*

You can listen for notification clicks for Data payloads by adding the following to your firebase-messaging.js file:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();

  // Do something as the result of the notification click
});
```

## *Notification Close*

You can listen for notification close events with:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclose', function(event) {
  // Do something as the result of the notification close
});
```

> **Ref: [notificationclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/notificationclick)**

Comment: I know that..I am asking that I have to know the count of the users who clicked the notification send through this add event listener.